# Does Covariance Improve Variance of Random Variable?

Tags: variance, covariance

I read a while back that we use covariance to improve the variance (conditional variance) of some random variable (i believe this was in context to Kalman filter). This concept is bit intriguing me for now so I want to clarify. So if we have a variance of some random variable $x$ and we know there is a correlation with some other random variable $y$. Now will knowing the covariance between the two random variable will help us improve the conditional variance of the random variable?

$$\textrm{Is}\ \sigma_x > \sigma_{x|cov(x,y)}\ \textrm{?}$$

So in otherwords if we find all the covariates of a random variable, will the random variable still be random?

Answer (score 0):

This is the foundation of linear models, which, you probably already know, are widely applicable and almost always useful at least somehow. In linear models, total SS of the target variable is equal to the sum of SS of y|x and of SS explained by the model.

from SS variance is estimated dividing it by the number of degrees of freedom, so in general, if y is correlated to the covariates, $\sigma_{y|x} < \sigma_y$.

However, this doesn't always apply. Exceptions aren't common, but in the case of heteroscedasticity, for some x, $\sigma^2_{y|x}$ can be greater than marginal variance of y.

This holds in general for any x. If you are interested in the overall behaviour of $\sigma^2_{y|x}$, maybe the [tower law of variance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) is what you are looking for, and its implications are clear: conditioned variance is often lower than marginal one.